# Barclays PINsentry + PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, binary

To answer this question, you should be aware of what [PINsentry](http://www.barclays.co.uk/Helpsupport/IntroducingPINsentryforOnlineBanking/P1242559314766) is first, of course.

I am writing a project for my personal use, that would allow me to enter the card number & pin (possibly other information as well): the script will generate the PINsentry code and allow me to monitor my income.

I wonder whether it is possible to generate this code using PHP? or the method is considered secret?

I found [this code](http://aa.gg/free/barclays-pinsentry.c), which is written in C, though I am not particularly good at it and can't really tell the exact purpose of the code.

p.s. If there is an alternative way to do this, which would allow me to perform this operation without every time entering my data, let me know.

Comment: http://www.barclays.co.uk/Helpsupport/IntroducingPINsentryforOnlineBanking/P1242559314766

Comment: Is this a recent improvement? In the Netherlands all major banks use such a token for authorization of payments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is alternative way to **login using passcode & memorable word**. This would allow your script to check the balance and monitor income.

For the first time you would need to login to your Barclays Online Banking with PINSentry and set up passcode and memorable word.

This alternative way of login allows you to access your account, check your balance etc. However, for money transfers you would still need to use PINSentry. This would give additional security if your script/program is compromised as it gives only limited access to your account.

---

*From Barclays Online Banking:*

> If you don't want to carry your PINsentry card reader around with you all the time, you don't have to. You can set up a passcode and memorable word here and use them to log in when you don't have it. You’ll be able to see balances, transfer money between your Barclays accounts and make payments to people and companies you've paid before through Online Banking. To access the full payments service, however, you'll still need to use PINsentry.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely need you debit card and PINSentry to generate one-time code, no script or C program alone can help you to do this. The reason is that PINSentry interacts with your card in order to check your PIN in the first place. I don't know if the protocol is secret, but even if it's not (which I doubt, RSA tokens use secret protocol for instance) without your card and the reader you won't be able to generate the code.

What you *can* do is use Barclays' basic access and automate your browser to enter your details for you. Or you can create a PHP program which will be using HTTP requests to 'fill' in the necessary information, including your card number and your secret word's letters. But you have to be **extremely** carefull since if someone gets access to your program then he or she will immediately get access to your account with all the consequences.